# How can I call all the custom post type?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I would like to insert all the custom post type in one page and the pagination. I just can call one custom post type. What can I do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qrLB.png)

Comment: post_type => 'any' , also change posts_per_page to -1 if you want all posts

Comment: When I put any it doesn't work

Comment: try like `'post_type' => array('post','page','event')`

Comment: What I put in event?

Comment: It worked with any now. I don't know why, but it worked. Thank's a lot

Answer (score 2):

What @vel is referring to is the fact that if you want to call more than one custom post type, you need to place them in an array, as he demonstrated.

Let’s say you have two custom post types: `event` and `book`.

You would then place these post types in your array like so:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'event', 'book' ),
);
```

I hope that helps.